# Whoosh Functionality

Tags: python, whoosh

I have over 700 small, locally stored text files (no more that 2Kb large). Each file is located in a folder such as:

- `2012//05//18.txt`
- `2013//09/22.txt`
- `2014//11//29.txt`

(each file represents a day).

The content contains daily "incident" information. I'm interested in being able to locate files containing specific words.

1. Can files be indexed by whoosh in bulk ?  That is, can python/whoosh code be written to index a set of files ?
2. If so, can a python script be written to search for specific words within each file ?
3. If this is not the functionality of whoosh, or if whoosh is overkill for such a task, what can better accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: I've never used whoosh. I just read the [quickstart](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/quickstart.html#the-indexwriter-object).

Seems like this would be pretty trivial to accomplish. The crux of the work you'll have to do is here:

```
writer.add_document(title=u"First document", path=u"/a", content=u"This is the first document we've added!")
```

This is where the index is actually created. Essentially, what it seems you will have to do is use something like [os.walk](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) to crawl your root directory, and fill in the data, and for each file it finds, fill in the `writer.add_document` params.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/your/path/to/logs"):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
        with open(filepath, 'r') as content_file:
            file_contents = content_file.read()
            writer.add_document(title=file, content=the_contents, path=filepath)
```

That's a starting point at least. It seems pretty straightforward to use the Searcher provided by Whoosh to run through your indexed files after that.

```
with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse("somesearchstring")
    results = searcher.search(query)
    print(results)
```

Like I said I've never used whoosh but this is what I would do were I you.

Comment: I found the following few lines in www.ocf.berkely.edu: for path in my_docs(): add_doc(writer,path).  Along with and add_doc(writer, path) method that includes fileobj=open(path) content=fileobj.read()....writer.add_document(path=path, content=content).  This SEEMS like what I would need to piece together to get this to work.  I just wanted to be certain I wasn't embarking on trying to use a tool that doesn't have the functionality I need.  It seems, based on what you indicate, and these few lines I found, that it might do the work.

Comment: Yup this is definitely a very feasible thing to do. not sure what my_docs() is. I just based my code on the quickstart for whoosh. os.walk allows you to go through an entire directory recursively, which i think suits your needs.